# What equation would this curve have? $f(x,y) = $ square with Gaussian sides

Tags: geometry, functions

What I want is a function that takes $x$ and $y$ and gives me $f(x,y)$ in the shape of a square, whose sides have been smoothed by a Gaussian.

For example, I can concoct and plot this function:

$$ f(x,y) = \mathrm{e}^{-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2/0.1} $$[image]

which is a ring smoothed by a Gaussian.

What would be the equation for the same kind of curve, but in the shape of a square (with rounded corners)? I am certain there must be a way I can introduce "roundness/asymmetry" parameters $a$ and $b$ such that $a=b=1$ corresponds to the circle (above) but that, in general, can give a squaroid-like shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) way:

$$
f(x,y) = \exp(-((x^{2n}+y^{2n})^{1/{2n}}-3)^2/0.1)
$$
It gets more and more "squaroid" as increases. Here $a=b=1$, but you can use different parameters to get a more rectangular shape.